# Are the Access Key Id and Secret Access Key related in a known way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cryptography, credentials

I'd like to be able to verify that a secret key matches a given "Access Key Id" if possible. I thought perhaps the key Id was some sort of hash of the secret key, but I'm not finding documentation for this.

**EDIT**: upon closer inspection, I wonder whether the access key id is derived from a timestamp...

Comment: I can see that this is a asymmetric key. Normally the ID is calculated by performing a SHA-1 hash over the modulus. Just a hint...

Comment: I don't know the answer, but there is clearly no reason for them to be related. The secret access key is a shared secret (both you and AWS know it), so they could just keep it in a data store indexed by the access key id. Note that they can't keep a hashed version of the secret access key, because they have to be able to look it up to calculate the signature to check it. If they were using asymmetric cryptography, they wouldn't need to know your secret.